# Search and Parse Large XML Index from Tasker

Tags: android, xml, large-files, tasker

The site: http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/index.xml; is an index of US weather stations tagged with Lat/Lon coordinates that gives current local weather observations. Of the 2257 stations in the file, each 10 line segment looks like this:

```
<station>
    <station_id>PADK</station_id>
    <state>AK</state>
    <station_name>Adak Island, Adak Airport</station_name>
    <latitude>51.87778</latitude>
    <longitude>-176.64583</longitude>
    <html_url>http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/PADK.html</html_url>
    <rss_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/PADK.rss</rss_url>
    <xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/PADK.xml</xml_url>
</station>
```

The goal is to use the android phone's GPS and Maps route information to search for the closest Latitude/Longitude match then drop down 2 lines and use that RSS link to parse and pass to a TTS service; as the phone is being automated for a 'hands free' experience while driving. From Tasker one would normally 'Get' the site which loads the global var %HTTPD and parse from there, but the file far exceeds the variable size limit. Does anyone have a suitable workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `HttpURLConnection` like:

```
URL url = new URL("http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/index.xml");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

And then get your `InputStream` and parse it using SAX Parser like:

```
 // get a new SAXParser
 SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
 // parse the stream
 parser.parse(is, handler);
```

Where `handler` is your class extending `HandlerBase` class.

SAX Parser is stream-based XML parser. There're a lot of examples of SAX Parser around. Just Google them.

Comment: There may be a simple way around using the NWS XML index file at all. A Google Maps intent to query for National Weather Service. Each location links to srh.noaa.gov/xxx, where the three letter designation for that station can be substituted in the standard RSS link, e.g., 'http://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=HGX&product=AFD&format=CI&version=1&glossary=0' (Where HGX indicates the Houston/Galveston station transmitter.) I'm investigating how to capture that link from the Maps location information. Let you know how I do.

Comment: Sorry. Don't know how to display the whole text of the RSS link.

Comment: You should write SAX parser, which handles your link and as a result creates array of stations with their lattitute/longitude, etc. Based on that array you can select closiest one.

Comment: After having done some more research, I see that yours is the correct answer; a viable solution to the question posed.